# Why is the wrong value being calculated

Tags: c++

I have a program that calculates the cost of phone calls with different rates for different days and times. The rates are as follow:

- Any call made between 8:00am and 6:00pm, Monday through Friday, is billed at a rate of $0.40 per minute.
- Any call made before 8:00am or after 6:00pm, Monday through Friday, is charged at a rate of $0.25 per minute.
- Any call made on a Saturday or Sunday is charged at a rate of $0.15 per minute.
- Any call whose duration spans across multiple rate zones is charged based on the actual minutes in the corresponding rate zones.

My code gives the right values for every log except for the last one, which is supposed to be $6.50 but is instead $4.50.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

string makeTimeIntoInt(string line[]) {
    string temp = "";
    string time = line[1];
    for (char a : time) {
        if (a == ':')
            continue;
        else
            temp += a;
    }

    return temp;
}

string nextDay(string day){
    if(day == "Mo") return "Tu";
    else if(day == "Tu") return "We";
    else if(day == "We") return "Th";
    else if(day == "Th") return "Fr";
    else if(day == "Fr") return "Sa";
    else if(day == "Sa") return "Su";
    else if(day == "Su") return "Mo";

    return day;
}

int convertSixtySecondsToHour(int time){
    if(time == 060) time = 100;
    else if(time == 160) time = 200;
    else if(time == 260) time = 300;
    else if(time == 360) time = 400;
    else if(time == 460) time = 500;
    else if(time == 560) time = 600;
    else if(time == 660) time = 700;
    else if(time == 760) time = 800;
    else if(time == 860) time = 900;
    else if(time == 960) time = 1000;
    else if(time == 1060) time = 1100;
    else if(time == 1160) time = 1200;
    else if(time == 1260) time = 1300;
    else if(time == 1360) time = 1400;
    else if(time == 1460) time = 1500;
    else if(time == 1560) time = 1600;
    else if(time == 1660) time = 1700;
    else if(time == 1760) time = 1800;
    else if(time == 1860) time = 1900;
    else if(time == 1960) time = 2000;
    else if(time == 2060) time = 2100;
    else if(time == 2160) time = 2200;
    else if(time == 2260) time = 2300;
    else if(time == 2360) time = 000;
    return time;
}

float calculateCost(string line[]) {
    int time = stoi(makeTimeIntoInt(line));
    int duration = stoi(line[2]);
    string day = line[0];
    float totalCost = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= duration; i++){
    if (line[0] == "Mo" || line[0] == "Tu" || line[0] == "We" ||
        line[0] == "Th" || line[0] == "Fr") {
        if (time < 800 || time > 1800) {
            totalCost += 0.25;
        } else
            totalCost += 0.4;
    }

    else if (line[0] == "Sa" || line[0] == "Su") {
        totalCost += 0.15;
    }
        time++;
        time = convertSixtySecondsToHour(time);
            if(time == 000){
            day = nextDay(day);
        }
    }
    return totalCost;
}

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile;
    string line;
    int cnt = 0;
    inputFile.open("/Users/wonder-intern/Documents/C++ Workspace/PhoneRecords/PhoneRecords/calls_history.txt"); //change this to the path of the txt file
    string arr[18];
    string line1[3], line2[3], line3[3], line4[3], line5[3], line6[3];
    float costLine1, costLine2, costLine3, costLine4, costLine5, costLine6;

    if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "file could not be opened\n\n";
        return 0;
    }

    while (getline(inputFile, line) && cnt < 18) {
        istringstream split(line);
        split >> arr[cnt];
        cnt++;
        split >> arr[cnt];
        cnt++;
        split >> arr[cnt];
        cnt++;
    }

    inputFile.close();
    line1[0] = arr[0];
    line1[1] = arr[1];
    line1[2] = arr[2];
    line2[0] = arr[3];
    line2[1] = arr[4];
    line2[2] = arr[5];
    line3[0] = arr[6];
    line3[1] = arr[7];
    line3[2] = arr[8];
    line4[0] = arr[9];
    line4[1] = arr[10];
    line4[2] = arr[11];
    line5[0] = arr[12];
    line5[1] = arr[13];
    line5[2] = arr[14];
    line6[0] = arr[15];
    line6[1] = arr[16];
    line6[2] = arr[17];

    costLine1 = calculateCost(line1);
    costLine2 = calculateCost(line2);
    costLine3 = calculateCost(line3);
    costLine4 = calculateCost(line4);
    costLine5 = calculateCost(line5);
    costLine6 = calculateCost(line6);

    cout << "Day Time Duration Cost\n\n";

    cout << line1[0] << " " << line1[1] << " " << line1[2] << " $" << costLine1
    << "\n";

    cout << line2[0] << " " << line2[1] << " " << line2[2] << " $" << costLine2
    << "\n";

    cout << line3[0] << " " << line3[1] << " " << line3[2] << " $" << costLine3
    << "\n";

    cout << line4[0] << " " << line4[1] << " " << line4[2] << " $" << costLine4
    << "\n";

    cout << line5[0] << " " << line5[1] << " " << line5[2] << " $" << costLine5
    << "\n";

    cout << line6[0] << " " << line6[1] << " " << line6[2] << " $" << costLine6
    << "\n";

    cout << "Total: $"
    << costLine1 + costLine2 + costLine3 + costLine4 + costLine5 + costLine6
    << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The text file with the call log can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bysk6_x4B46uQko4dEpMNXZtY2M

Comment: Have you tried to debug this code?

Comment: This `if(time == 060)` is actually `if(time == 48)`.

Comment: yes I have, I know that the new rate is not being applied but I don't know why

Comment: what do you mean DimChtz?

Comment: I mean `60` and `060` are 2 different things. `060` means octal(60)

Comment: @RoeiBurstein - Integral constants starting with `0` are octal, not decimal.

Comment: A teacher of mine had a term 'Gabe-ified' after a student he liked to make an example of, Gabe, who would never write trivial math and algorithms and would write everything as massive if-else ladders. On that note, I recommend you spare yourself dozens of lines of code and many headaches with maintainability by averting from giant if-else ladders.

Comment: I changed 060 to 60 but that doesn't change the result

Comment: @RoeiBurstein -  You don't see a pattern in that giant set if if / else statements, like `time = (time + 40) % 2400`?

Comment: you also have a `time = 000` in there and a `time == 000`

Comment: @RoeiBurstein Also `if (a == ':') continue; else temp += a;` can be shorter, you need to learn when to use 2D array (in `main`) and loops with modulo operator, and shorten logical expressions using De Morgan's laws.

Comment: @RoeiBurstein `string line1[3], line2[3], line3[3], line4[3], line5[3], line6[3];`  why not simply `string line[6][3]`;?  And this: `float costLine1, costLine2, costLine3, costLine4, costLine5, costLine6;` -- why not `float costLine[6];`? Once you have this, then all you need is a loop to process the lines, not 6 separate statements.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the pattern is not the issue, I know my code is sloppily written but it's graded on accuracy not on style or how well it's made. Despite all of your suggestions I still get the wrong output for the last line of the log

Comment: @RoeiBurstein -- The comment section on SO are for comments, not answers.  I am commenting on your code.  And believe it or not, redundant, copy / paste coding that you have done leads to errors occurring.

Comment: I am not looking for suggestions on how to make it shorter and nicer but I'm on a bit of a time crunch and just wanted to get it done. All I need is the root to the wrong value

Comment: It isn't about shorter and nicer -- as my comment states, redundant code like this where you pile on the lines makes it more susceptible to errors occurring.  A 2 line loop is less likely to have errors than a 20 line set of `if` statements.

Comment: I definitely agree with you, and if I were to have many errors and a confusing mess of code I would work on changing it, but I have literally 1 mistake in the code until it works flawlessly, and I don't think it's worth changing the structure of everything to fix one error

Comment: @RoeiBurstein I am not sure but maybe here `int time = stoi(makeTimeIntoInt(line));` you really mean `int time = convertSixtySecondsToHour(stoi(makeTimeIntoInt(line)));`?

Comment: Please post or hard-code the data into your post that causes the error.  It is useless if the data that causes the issue is on another site.

Comment: it's not an error that's causing the program not to run, it's an error in the calculation that's not giving me the intended value

Comment: Your program cannot run without data.  What is the data?

Comment: @DimChtz it did not change anything. The problem is that costLine6 is 4.5 and not 6.5

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie do you mean the txt file?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by data

Comment: @RoeiBurstein - Do you really believe that we're going to run the program in our heads to debug it?  Please provide just one set of input that duplicates the issue that you're seeing.

Comment: It should be 0.15*10 + 0.25*20

Comment: You're giving us a calculation -- gives us the data that you are reading in for this one particular case that is not giving the right results.

Comment: Input: Su 23:50 30

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you meant by data

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1) `060` is actually octal which in decimal is 48. So, remove all leading zeros. 
2) Inside `calculateCost` change:

```
if (line[0] == "Mo" || line[0] == "Tu" || line[0] == "We" ||
    line[0] == "Th" || line[0] == "Fr")
```

to:

```
if (day == "Mo" || day == "Tu" || day == "We" ||
    day == "Th" || day == "Fr")
```

and

```
else if (line[0] == "Sa" || line[0] == "Su")
```

to

```
else if (day == "Sa" || day == "Su")
```

because when you call `day = nextDay(day);` obviously you change `day` and not `line[0]`. You 're getting `4.5` because `line[0]` remains `"Su"`. Only `day` changes to `"Mo"`.